# Shorter version of assigning to a member of a derived class by an instance of a base-class

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, derived-class

Consider this small example:

```
public class BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass { public int Field; }

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main( string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass baseVar = new DerivedClass();

        if( baseVar is DerivedClass )
        {
            var derivedVar = (DerivedClass)baseVar;

            derivedVar.Field = 1;

            baseVar = derivedVar;
        }
    }
}
```

I have alot of code like this in if-conditions. Is there a shorthand version of this, so I do not have to create a temporary derived variable?

Comment: Note that this kind of code is referred as a code-smell. Try to find a common interface or base class to combine common classes and try to use these interface. It is less error-prone and decreases the maintenance effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be safe typecasting:

```
BaseClass base = new DerivedClass();
DerivedClass derived = base as DerivedClass;
derived?.Field = 1;
```

Note: `as` is safe casting - which will either cast or return null. `?` is a C#6 Feature, where the method or the assignment is executing when the variable is not a `nullPtr`. You do not have to write `baseVar = derivedVar`, since both are bound by reference. When you cast and change the field, then the reference hasn't changed at all.

Also, here's a MSDN article on null propagation in C#6.0 https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/dn802602.aspx

For the sake of compliance, that's the veriant OP chose:

```
BaseClass base = new DerivedClass();
(base as DerivedClass)?.Field = 1;
```

Comment: I wanted to keep it in the spirit of the given example. Short is nice, but I think for maintainability and clarity pulling this bit apart seems a lot clearer (and hopefully gets optimized by the compiler to your solution anyway). But I agree, this works too.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go with @ZoharPeled 's comment above! (I have several hundrets of such expressions, currently all wrapped in if-conditions. The shorter the better for now :)

Comment: @MioBambino Basically I agree with your claim, however in this case I don't think it hurts readability that much.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I see no issue with that, either. It's just me as an overdeclaring (originally) java developer.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment

```
baseVar = derivedVar;
```

is redundant so you can just do

```
if( baseVar is DerivedClass ) {
    ((DerivedClass)baseVar).Field = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought casting woul result in a temporary variable that will be discarded immediately if not assigned? Seems I was wrong

Comment: It will be. But the variable only stores the reference - not the entire data of the object. Discarding the reference will not result in discards of the changes to the object.

Comment: So to say, this is different to C/C++ then?